# How to push Web Service in Variable in Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I want to push dynamic web service data to **TRACKONE** inside **app.service.ts** file.

I've created a server on the link which is projecting the JSON in the same order as displayed below in **Track[ ]**.

```
[
  {id: 11, name: 'App1'},
  {id: 12, name: 'App2'},
  {id: 13, name: 'App3'},
  {id: 14, name: 'App4'}
];
```

Also fetched the data from the server and stored in a function using **Http**, which is getting the data and refreshing data after every 5 sec interval and displaying it in **console**.

```
private serviceUrl = "http://localhost:9000/service";

constructor(private http: Http){
  this.getService();
}

getServiceOne(interval: number): Observable<Track[]> {
  return Observable.timer(0,interval)
  .mergeMap(()=>{
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl)
      .map(res => res.json());
  });
}

getService() {
  this.getServiceOne(5000).subscribe(posts => {
    console.log(this.posts = posts);
  })
}
```

I just need to pass the JSON value from **getService()** to **export var TRACKONE: Track[ ]**

```
export class Track {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export var TRACKONE: Track[] = [
  {id: 11, name: 'App1'},
  {id: 12, name: 'App2'},
  {id: 13, name: 'App3'},
  {id: 14, name: 'App4'},
];
```

Kindly help in finding the right solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you just want to overwrite the data, why not: `.subscribe(posts => {TRACKONE = posts})`?

Comment: It does not work. I need the static data inside TRACKONE to be replaced by the web service. But if I subscribe TRACKONE inside getService() then it shows error when I'm getting TRACKONE in another function as it is not globally exported.

Comment: You'd need to share some more code. Where is `TRACKONE` declared? Please share the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, I need to call the **getServiceOne( )** function in components rather than in service, because of that i was facing the issue.

Now I have added the below line in **component.ts** file and imported the **service.ts** file, it's working fine.

```
getTrackOnes(): void {
  this.trackoneService.getServiceOne(5000).subscribe(tracks => {this.tracks = tracks;});
}
```